# Idiomatic Scala to build collection B from collection A

Tags: scala

I have one collection A and I need to create a collection B from collection A. In the simplest case, one could hope to use the `map`method, but I am looking for a solution where at each step in the creation of elements of B, it is needed to have access to the elements already in the collection.

I have in mind multiple possibilities to create B:

- Using a mutable collection for B and then turn it into an immutable
- Using the builder underlying the collection B
- Using a foldLeft with an empty B and grow it inside the closure

Is there an idiomatic approach, or at least a way to pick up one according to different use cases?

Answer (score 6):

The most idiomatic is the `foldLeft` -- folds come quite naturally on functional programming. Another possibility would be a `scanLeft`, which might slightly decrease the bookkeeping.

On the other hand, what this really looks like is an iteration over a `State` monad. The book [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/) has something quite like that as one of its exercises.

The `State` monad is basically a monad over type `A` for a function of `S => (S, A)`, though it is usually declared as a proper type with some specialty methods that makes common operations easier.

In your example, the state, `S`, would be an `Option[A]` of the last result (or, if appropriate, the "zero" of `A`). You'd then map your collection from it's type `T` into functions of `S => (S, A)` (or a state monad type), getting a `Coll[S => (S, A)]`.

From there you can `sequence` it (`sequence` is something that turns `M[N[A]]` into `N[M[A]]` for monads `M` and `N` -- see [The Essence of the Iterator Pattern](http://etorreborre.blogspot.com.br/2011/06/essence-of-iterator-pattern.html)), obtaining `S => (S, Coll[A])`, feed it the initial state, and then retrieve the `Coll[A]`.

There are many resources on the web about state monad, though I personally found it more difficult to get a handle on than most other monads. Someone mentioned to me that might be because the "state" monad is misnamed, and it is really a "state processor" monad, which makes sense to me.

Anyway, from your alternatives the `foldLeft` is the most idiomatic, but the state monad approach is very appropriate for this task.

Comment: What would be the advantage of using the State Monad over foldLeft?

Answer (score 5):

I would certainly argue that foldLeft is the most idiomatic approach. That's precisely what I had in mind prior to reading your possibilities.

Comment: BTW, Your question is quite timely. I'm working on a blog post to help guys like us who are programmatically imperative grapple with the basic collection operations. I'll add it here once I publish it later today.

Comment: Posted: [Map, reduce, and fold for the programmatically imperative](http://proseand.co.nz/2013/09/09/map-reduce-and-fold-for-the-programmatically-imperative/)